# Getting authorization code from redirect_uri for Exact API using python

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, exact-online

Update: Edited the code with the working version. You can use it to retrieve your authorization code.

I have been trying to figure out how to return the authorization code. I am new to API communication therefore I might be missing something crucial here. I am able to login but I just cant return the code. Please help me out people of exact!

Auth end point is https://start.exactonline.nl/api/oauth2/auth
Token end point is https://start.exactonline.nl/api/oauth2/token

```
import requests
import urllib.parse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

user = ''

psw = ''

params = {'client_id': "",
    'redirect_uri': "",
    'response_type': "code",
    'force_login': "1"}

url = 'https://start.exactonline.nl/api/oauth2/auth/'
token_url = 'https://start.exactonline.nl/api/oauth2/token'

with requests.session() as s:
    OAuth_AccessRequest = s.get(url,params=params)
    
OAuthURL = OAuth_AccessRequest.url
soup = BeautifulSoup(OAuth_AccessRequest.content)
form = soup.form
login_data = {e['name']: e.get('value', '') for e in form.find_all('input', {'name': True})}
login_data.update({'UserNameField': user, 'PasswordField': psw})
login_data.update({'hf2StepLoginStep': 1})
login_url = OAuthURL.format(form.attrs['action'])

with requests.session() as s:
    Actual_login = s.get(login_url, params=login_data)
    
Authorization_code=Actual_login.url.split("https://salesanalysisexact.herokuapp.com/?code=")[-1]
Authorization_code=urllib.parse.unquote(Authorization_code)
print (Authorization_code)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added the below code and I could see the redirec_uri with the authorization code. I guess I was just not making the right request type.

```
code_url = s.get(login_url,params=login_data)
```